# Passing non-final integer in another class

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, integer, final

I have this problem: I want to execute multiple threads at once, using a for-loop. I want to pass the variable "i" to a method in the thread. But there is an error occuring, I cannot pass a non-final variable "i" into another class. How can I fix that? This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // 4 THREADS AT ONCE
  thread[i] = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      randomMethod(i); // ERROR HERE
    }
  };
  thread[i].start();
}
```

Comment: Create a `final` variable inside the loop that's initialised to the value of `i`, and pass that instead.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr , no it won't be sufficient , you can not change the value of final variable !

Comment: You don't have to change it? Just "final int k = i;" and pass k instead of i. Or create a non anonymous sub class of thread and pass i to its constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // 4 THREADS AT ONCE
  final int temp=i;
  thread[i] = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      randomMethod(temp); // ERROR HERE
    }
  };
  thread[i].start();
}
```

Comment: @NeerajJain That's not true. Declaring a variable inside the loop and assigning `i` will work.

Comment: @John Vint I intended to respond to the identical comment in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a code similar to the following:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int i;

    public MyRunnable(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        randomMethod(i); 
    }
}

// In another class
...
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // 4 THREADS AT ONCE
    thread[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable(i));
}
thread[i].start();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there is quite a lot of ways to solve this problem, but it is important to know WHY an error occurs.

It is because Java creates a copy of final variable used in anonymous class to this class. If this variable isn't final, there is no guarantee that you are going to have always the right (newest) version of this variable. So, **you can not use any non-final local variables in anonymous class declaration** (since Java 8 effectively final is enough).